# How to hide Application Window when its EXE has been called from a Process?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-services

I'm running an application's EXE using a Class Library **from a Service**.
But what i'm attempting to do is hide the application EXE's Window.
Here is my code:

In my Class Library's function:-

```
public class MyClassLibrary
{
    public void MyFunction()
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyFolder\MyApp.exe";
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.Start();
    }
}
```

And this is where i'm calling it from:

```
class MyClass : ServiceBase
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        MyClassLibrary obj = new MyClassLibrary();
        obj.MyFunction();
    }
}
```

Despite all of the above, the window is yet seen.
Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Thanks and Regards,
Siddhant

Comment: Weird, that shouldn't happen. Also; is the interact with desktop setting for you service on or off? Check your Service properties

Comment: Actually i think i'll modify my question a bit more..

Comment: May be (C# - Launch Invisible Process [CreateNoWindow & WindowStyle not working?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011209/c-sharp-launch-invisible-process-createnowindow-windowstyle-not-working) helps

Comment: @GeraldVersluis - I was unable to find that setting..

Comment: @Arne - I tried this but it didn't work.. Thanx for helping out though.. :)

Comment: @Siddhant I meant this setting; http://www.ozekisms.com/attachments/571/service_interact_with_desktop.gif

Comment: @GeraldVersluis - Oh.. Yeah, the check was off.. Turned it on.. But it still didn't help.. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code in does not work but

But when i try it this way it works fine

```
string filePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe";    
ProcessStartInfo pStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(filePath );
pStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

> Reason it works with Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo) because it
>   associates the given information with a new component as explained on
>   [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer guys, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3011731/1051651) comment, which i got from [Arne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1472628/arne)'s comment at the top of this question.. Apparently it seems that the **Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute** was supposed to be set to **true**.

Thanks everyone for helping out! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
string filePath = @"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe";
ProcessStartInfo pStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(filePath);

**pStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;** 

pStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;   
Process.Start(pStartInfo);
```

**Note:** Set `pStartInfo.UseShellExecute` to `true` otherwise you get an error