# Opening a process in C# with hidden window

Tags: c#

I have a function for starting processes on a local machine:

```
public int StartProcess(string processName, string commandLineArgs = null)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = processName;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = commandLineArgs;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    process.Start();
    return process.Id;
}
```

It is supposed to start the process without opening a new window. Indeed, when I test it with timeout.exe no console window is opened. But when I test it with notepad.exe or calc.exe their windows still open.

I saw online that this method works for other people. I'm using .NET 4.0 on Windows 7 x64.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the source where it works for other people?

Comment: I don't think that there's a general way to launch another executable and then *prevent* that executable from deciding to open its own windows.

Comment: I agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Generally if a process decide to open a window, it requires user interaction, so it usually won't function without a window. Unlike console applications, where you can programmatically read and write to the standard input/output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011209/c-sharp-launch-invisible-process-createnowindow-windowstyle-not-working. Chris Schmich says that it works on his machine. @AlvinWong

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks. I will stick to hiding only console applications.

Answer (score 3):

The CreateNoWindow flag applies to Console processes only.

See here for the details:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx

Secondly applications can ignore the WindowStyle argument - it has effect the first time the new application calls ShowWindow, but subsequent calls are under the control of the application.

Comment: This is why I added the Hidden WindowStyle.

Answer (score 2):

Following program will show/hide the window:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    const int SW_SHOW = 5;

    static void Main()
    {
        // The 2nd argument should be the title of window you want to hide.
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Untitled - Notepad");
        if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            //ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
            ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE); // Hide the window
        }
    }
}
```

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/1bc7dee4-bf1a-4c41-802e-b25941e50fd9

Comment: What do *you* see when you look at line 4 of the OPs `StartProcess` method? (Hmm. Maybe I miscounted, or maybe I subconsciously started counting from 0, but hopefully the point still works)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yes, missed it.

Comment: +1 this seems to be the most powerful method e.g. it works on calc where other methods fail. Besides findwindow  , you can get a process's handle. Then as you do,  hide the process`     IntPtr blah=p.MainWindowHandle; ShowWindow(blah, SW_HIDE);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false`

```
    public int StartProcess(string processName, string commandLineArgs = null)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = processName;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = commandLineArgs;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.Start();
        return process.Id;
    }
```

Comment: did you test this on calc?

Comment: testing with cmd.exe, (and not a console application project).  I agree with `You need to remove the process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false` but oddly enough  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx  says "To use ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden, the ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute property must be false."